# sending request parameter from action method to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a form with a drop down list in a JSP page

```
<html:form action="/accountProcess">
        <html:hidden property="dispatch" value="getUsers" />
          <select name="user_status_filter" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <option value="Status">Status</option>
            <option value="all" >All</option>
            <option value="inactive">Inactive</option>
            <option value="active">Active</option>
          </select>
</html:form>
```

in my action method I'm doing the following:

```
String requestValue = RequestUtils.getStringParameter(request, "user_status_filter");
```

and it's working great, but I also want to send back the same exact string so that I can add the "selected" string to the right option element to keep it selected when the form is submitted.

right now I'm doing this in my action method

```
request.setAttribute("selectedValue", requestValue);
```

but I don't know how to add conditional logic to my jsp so that it's something like

```
if (${selectedValue}.equals("all")
<option value="all" selected>All</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<option value="all" ${selectedValue == 'all' ? 'selected' : ''}>All</option>
```

Just change the value you compare it to in every `<option>`.

Comment: it's not working... is there a step between request.setAttribute and the jsp finding it?

Comment: You are doing a full post, right? Not AJAX request?

Comment: yea full post, not AJAX, page refreshed on form submit, action method returns the following: return mapping.findForward("adminView")

Comment: Can you print out `${selectedValue}` somewhere on the page, just to check if it is returned?

Comment: do I just do <%out.print(${selectedValue})%> somewhere on the page?

Comment: Just put `${selectedValue}` anywhere, without `<% ... %>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63170/discussion-between-predrag-maric-and-abdul-ahmad).